# Googleフォーム送信時のトリガーにおける原因不明のエラー「Exception: フォームのデータを取得できませんでした。しばらくしてからもう一度お試しください。」

Tags: google-apps-script

現在Google フォームの送信時をトリガーとして、gasの関数を実行するということをしています。
普段は問題なく使えているのですが、最近三件ほどトリガーがエラーを出していて、エラーの原因が不明です。基本はうまく行っていて、エラーが起こる条件もわからず、確かめることも難しい状況になっています。

そのため分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただければ幸いです。
また、エラー文で検索しても一件も引っ掛からなかったので、もし同じようなエラーを見たことがある人がいれば教えていただきたいです。

エラー文
**Exception: フォームのデータを取得できませんでした。しばらくしてからもう一度お試しください。**

[image: エラーの様子]
該当のコードは以下です。省略部分には問題はないと考えられます。

```
function notify(e) {
  //省略
​  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses(); //この行でエラー
 //省略
}
```

​フォームのデータを取得できませんでしたとあるので、ネットワークのエラーなのかなとも思い一旦様子を見ていたのですが、最近になって急に三件発生したため、ご質問させていただきました。​よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

私も同じ症状で悩んでいます。
エラー処理を入れようかと思ったのですが、「しばらくしてからもう一度お試しください。」とあるので、スレッド処理終了のタイミングの可能性もあるかと思い、e.response の前に１秒 sleep を入れて様子を見ています。
現象が原因不明かつ不定期、頻度も低いので、解決しているのかどうかは不明です。

Comment: 数日はエラーなく動作していましたが、やはり同じエラーが出ました。エラー処理を追加して様子を見ようと思います。